# Nativescript TextField max length

Tags: textfield, nativescript, maxlength

Is it possible to set maximum length of `TextField` in `Nativescript` using `javascript`? There is no `CSS` value for that. I haven't been able to get it working from `javascript` code.
Any idea,how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following thread where a possible solution for setting maxLenght is discussed : https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1508#issuecomment-180555668

Basically, the code provided from our community member is as follows:

```
let commentInputView = getViewById(page, "my-input")
commentInputView.on(textViewModule.TextView.propertyChangeEvent,  function(
eventData: ObservableEventData){
   if (eventData.propertyName == "text" && eventData.value.length > 10) {
      setTimeout(function() { commentInputView.text = eventData.value.substr(0, 9); }, 0);
   }
 });
```

This will force the input to be sub-stringed if it exceeds the desired max length (using the propertyChangedEvent to watch for the text-view property text - in your case you should do the same with the text-field).